# Expand div heights that only contains image with position absolute

Tags: css

```css
.aboutus {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 334px;
}

.aboutus__content {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  color: orange;
  max-width: 1800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.aboutus__imageWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='aboutus'>
    <div class='aboutus__content'>
      <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class='aboutus__imageWrapper'>
         <picture>
          <!-- Media query images go here -->
          <img src='https://www.visitmosselbay.co.za/wp-content/gallery/mossel-bay-photo-gallery/Mossel-Bay-Cape-St-Blaize-Lighthouse.jpg'>
        </picture>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

The idea is to make the image match the height of `aboutus` container. While the `aboutus` container height has min-height and also can be expanded but `aboutus__content` container.

I am a bit confused why `aboutus__imageWrapper` with `height: 100%` doesn't expand to the height of it's parent `aboutus`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove **overflow:hidden** from this rule:

```
.aboutus__imageWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```